# Undefined symbol when building qt program: qt_version_tag not found

Tags: qt

I am learning Qt5.6. I am working on Ubuntu 14.4.

I get the following error when I link my program:

```
undefined reference to `qt_version_tag'
```

In CMakeLists.txt:

```
link_libraries(
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Core
 )
```

Where is this symbol defined? What is missing in the link_libraries?

I used the following to construct my CMakeLists.txt:

https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/SOS/blob/master/25989448/issue/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 2):

The problem went away when I added the following to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
qt5_use_modules(MyProject Widgets)
```

I am not sure what exactly this does (some of the things CMake does are still mysterious to me). I got the idea by reading the following well written article:

https://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5/