# Why do I get this "error: undefined reference to `qt_version_tag' "?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am using Qt 5.7 on Ubuntu 16 LTS machine.

I get this error:

> (.qtversion[qt_version_tag]+0x0):-1: error: undefined reference to `qt_version_tag'

This error comes only when I use SDL libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbol when building qt program: qt\_version\_tag not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843001/undefined-symbol-when-building-qt-program-qt-version-tag-not-found)

Comment: Same here, but i'm not using CMake (i build project direclty from Qt Creator) and I think it's not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843001/undefined-symbol-when-building-qt-program-qt-version-tag-not-found

Answer (score 18):

I realize this is an old thread but you may be able to avoid it by defining QT_NO_VERSION_TAGGING; that is, by passing the option:

`-DQT_NO_VERSION_TAGGING`

to gcc.

Comment: Yup, this saved my day. For a .pro project file, add `DEFINES += QT_NO_VERSION_TAGGING`

Comment: Yes, or cmake: `add_definitions(-DQT_NO_VERSION_TAGGING)`