# Tesseract in QT

Tags: c++, qt, tesseract, leptonica

This is the first time I am asking a question here.

I want to use Tesseract API in QT.
My idea was to design a programme using QT that would read aloud messages (QSpeech) from Telegram Desktop version (not that important).

Tesseract came across as a tool I needed so I tried to implement it. I wanted to use its API, but finally I ended up using QProcess to call Tesseract as a programme.

HERE'S THE PROBLEM.

After including tesseract and leptonica libraries to .pro file i get this:

```
(.qtversion[qt_version_tag]+0x0):-1: error: undefined reference to `qt_version_tag'
```

How to fix it?

- I use QT 5_12_3

I included the libs.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include"
LIBS += -L"/usr/local/lib" -ltesseract

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include"
LIBS += -L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" -llept
```

I downloaded QT from the official website. Tesseract API code is an example taken from the documentation. From the same documentation I followed instructions to download everything needed. As I mentioned before, if I compile a text file with the code sample, then it works fine. I just can't integrate it into QT.

Comment: BTW I have everything needed installed. API in a text file works great. QT is the problem.

Comment: How you include tesseract and dependencies into your .pro? I guess you missed something

Comment: @mrNAE At first, I just right-clicked the project and chose "Add library" and added the .so files (leptonica and tesseract). After, I tried to write manually INCLUDEPATH and LIBS but it's all the same.

Comment: Have you seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871879/why-do-i-get-this-error-undefined-reference-to-qt-version-tag) yet?

Comment: @Carlton yep... unfortunately nothing changes

Comment: @RomanKartashow How have you installed or compiled X? Where did you download it from? please be precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tesseract and Leptonica create pkg-config files, so you didn't have to manually add `INCLUDEPATH` or `LIBS` to your project, instead use

```
QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
Config *= link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG *= tesseract
```

If it doesn't work for you, check whether the Tesseract is installed correctly (also check that you have `tesseract.pc` file in your system).

Comment: I put your code instead of `INCLUDEPATH` and `LIBS` and this is what I got:
-`Assignment needs exactly one word on the left hand side`
- `error: [Makefile] Error 3`

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault - an extra space `- =`. Fixed